# Is it possible to set the scham protocol to 'https' for only RspecApiDocumentation in specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-api-documentation

I want to render these through Apitome but they only return http. I'm able to set the other headers with:

```
        header 'Authorization', 'Token token=secret'
        header 'Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json'
        header 'Host', 'data.g2.com'
```

But when I pass up `header 'HTTP_CODE', 'https'` it scrubs it out, so it is either an issue with the key or I'm on the wrong track. Trying to avoid any monkey patching, but any tips would be welcomed!